# Wallabyjs - setting noEmitOnError to true produces errors

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, wallaby.js

I am using Wallabyjs with Visual Studio, Angular 5, Webpack and Typescript. After it now happend a few times, that code was pushed to the repository although there was a compilation error in the spec files, I wanted to activate noEmitOnError with

```
compilerOptions.noEmitOnError = true;
compilerOptions.useStandardDefaults = true;
```

in my wallaby.js configuration file. Unfortunately, I am now getting three errors and I cannot get rid of them. (Without setting noEmitOnError to true, everything works fine!) The errors are:

```
Postprocessor run failure: TypeScript compiler errors:
  - Error C:/Users/[NAME]/AppData/Local/Temp/.wallaby/projects/.../somefile.ts: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
  - Error: Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'.
  - Error: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
```

The file the first error is referring to is a normal .ts file with a reduced content:

```
import { SafeUrl } from "@angular/platform-browser";
```

If I remove this line, the error is gone. And as the "normal" typescript compilation is working it is perhaps redundant to say but in the folder node_modules/@types there are two folders for jasmine and node.

Any ideas? I searched the internet but didn't find much. [On one page](http://www.javascriptexamples.info/snippet/javascript/wallabyjs_hackur_javascript) I found something like this

```
Promise.all([System.import('@angular/core/testing'), System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')])
        .then(function (results) {
          var testing = results[0];
          var browser = results[1];
          testing.setBaseTestProviders(
```

but I have no clue on how to do something like this in my setup with webpack and typescript...

As it may help, here is my wallaby configuration:

```
var wallabyWebpack = require('wallaby-webpack');
var path = require('path');

var compilerOptions = Object.assign(
  require('./tsconfig.json').compilerOptions,
  require('./src/tsconfig.spec.json').compilerOptions);

compilerOptions.module = 'CommonJs';
compilerOptions.noEmitOnError = true; // you may skip it if it's already set in tsconfig
compilerOptions.useStandardDefaults = true;

module.exports = function (wallaby) {

  var webpackPostprocessor = wallabyWebpack({
    entryPatterns: [
      'src/wallabyTest.js',
      'src/**/*spec.js'
    ],

    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: ['raw-loader', 'css-loader'] },
        { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
        { test: /\.ts$/, loader: '@ngtools/webpack', include: /node_modules/, query: { tsConfigPath: 'tsconfig.json' } },
        { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'angular2-template-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
        { test: /\.styl$/, loaders: ['raw-loader', 'stylus-loader'] },
        { test: /\.less$/, loaders: ['raw-loader', 'less-loader'] },
        { test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/, loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
        { test: /\.(jpg|png)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=128000' }
      ]
    },

    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
      modules: [
        path.join(wallaby.projectCacheDir, 'src/app'),
        path.join(wallaby.projectCacheDir, 'src'),
        'node_modules'
      ]
    },
    node: {
      fs: 'empty',
      net: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty',
      dns: 'empty'
    }
  });

  return {
    files: [
      { pattern: 'src/**/*.+(ts|css|less|scss|sass|styl|html|json|svg)', load: false },
      { pattern: 'mocks/**/*.ts', load: false },
      { pattern: 'src/**/*.d.ts', ignore: true },
      { pattern: 'src/**/*spec.ts', ignore: true },
      '!src/test.ts',
      '!src/main.ts'
    ],

    tests: [
      { pattern: 'src/**/*spec.ts', load: false },
      { pattern: 'src/**/*e2e-spec.ts', ignore: true }
    ],

    testFramework: 'jasmine',

    compilers: {
      '**/*.ts': wallaby.compilers.typeScript(compilerOptions)
    },

    middleware: function (app, express) {
      var path = require('path');
      app.use('/favicon.ico', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/favicon.ico')));
      app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets')));
    },

    env: {
      kind: 'chrome'
    },

    postprocessor: webpackPostprocessor,

    setup: function () {
      window.__moduleBundler.loadTests();
    },

    debug: false
  };
};
```

And my tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],

        "plugins": [
            {
                "name": "tslint-language-service",
                "defaultSeverity": "error",
                "ignoreDefinitionFiles": true
            }
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help! 
Cheers

Comment: The `Cannot find type definition file for '...'` errors relate to the [`typeRoots` mechanism](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types); please add your `tsconfig.json` file to the question so we can understand what is going on there.  What code does the `Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'` error occur in?

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for your input! I updated my question and provided the information you asked for.

Comment: Thanks.  Given that the normal `tsc` compilation works, it looks like you have some module resolution or path searching problem specific to your Webpack/Wallaby configuration, which is something I know very little about.  Hopefully someone familiar with these tools will help.  If not, you can publish a repository that reproduces the problem and I will fiddle with it.

Comment: Matt, thanks again. I removed the content of the file and the first error disappears and no other errors appear. So the first error is perhaps something I could work around as unfortunately I also know very little about this Webpack/Wallaby configuration... But I think it is really strange that it cannot find jasmine and node. I'll investigate further... :) Thank you very much for your offer to fiddle perhaps I will come back to this later. First I'll do a deep dive by myself. But if you have any other ideas feel free to shout! ;)

Comment: I found one issue. I removed "require('./src/tsconfig.spec.json')" (don't know why it was there but it has the nasty entry "types": [
   "jasmine",
   "node"
  ]!) and now I only get the first error. Unfortunately I cannot work around it! :( So any help still highly appreciated!